# ReferenceError: check is not defined

Tags: node.js

Estou fazendo um curso de NodeJS e no projeto do instrutor é usado uma versão antiga do express-validator. Tentei adaptar o projeto para o uso da versão mais recente, mas ele só exibe a mensagem de **ReferenceError: check is not defined**

`server.js`

```js
var express = require('express');
var consign = require('consign');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var { check, expressValidator } = require('express-validator');
var app = express();

//MOTOR DE GERAÇÃO DE VIEWS
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.set('views', './app/views');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(check());

consign()
    .include('app/routes')
    .then('config/dbConnection.js')
    .then('app/models')
    .into(app);

module.exports = app;
```

`admin.js`

```js
module.exports = function (application) {
    application.get('/formulario_inclusao_noticia', function (req, res) {
        res.render("admin/form_add_noticia");
    });

    application.post('/noticias/salvar', function (req, res) {
        var noticia = req.body;

        check('titulo').isLength({ min: 5 }); 

        var errors = validationResult(req);

        if (errors) {
            console.log(errors.array());
            res.render("admin/form_add_noticia", { validacao: errors });
            return;
        }

        var connection = application.config.dbConnection();

        var noticiasModel = new application.app.models.NoticiasDAO(connection);

        noticiasModel.salvarNoticia(noticia, function (error, result) {
            res.redirect('/noticias');
        });
    });

}
```

`form_add_noticia.ejs`

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Formulário de cadastro de Notícia</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Adicionar notícia</h1>
    <br />



    <form action="/noticias/salvar" method="post">
        <label>Título</label>
        <input type="text" id="titulo" name="titulo" placeholder="Titulo da notícia" />
        <br />
        <label>Resumo</label>
        <input type="text" id="resumo" name="resumo" placeholder="Resumo da notícia" />
        <br />
        <label>Autor</label>
        <input type="text" id="autor" name="autor" placeholder="Autor da notícia" />
        <br />
        <label>Data</label>
        <input type="date" id="data_noticia" name="data_noticia" />
        <br />
        <label>Noticia</label>
        <textarea id="noticia" name="noticia" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

`NoticiasDAO.js`

```js
function NoticiasDAO(connection) {
    this._connection = connection;
}

NoticiasDAO.prototype.getNoticias = function (callback) {
    this._connection.query('select * from noticias', callback);
}

NoticiasDAO.prototype.getNoticia = function (callback) {
    this._connection.query('select * from noticias where id_noticia = 2', callback);
};

NoticiasDAO.prototype.salvarNoticia = function (noticia, callback) {
    this._connection.query('insert into noticias set ?', noticia, callback);
};

module.exports = function () {
    return NoticiasDAO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As novas versões do [`express-validator`](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/) (versão >= 6.x) utiliza outra nomenclatura e outro método de utilizar as funções, atualmente o código utilizado não será possível de integrar com as novas versões. O correto seria re-escrever as rotinas de validação.

Algumas mudanças notáveis é que a função check (foi desmembrada em `body`, `param` e `query` além disso agora não é mais necessário adicionar um middleware após o `body-parser`.

Dito isto minha sugestão é que você siga o guia de migração de `versão 5 para 6`. Os desenvolvedores do `express-validator` disponibilizaram um guia de como fazer a [`migração`](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/migration-v5-to-v6.html).

Estou disponibilizando um código que faz a validação de dados que vêm no corpo (body) da requisição de uma versão atualizada.

```
const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

exports.validationBodyRules = [
    body('login', 'login is required').exists(),
    body('password', 'password is required').exists(),
    body('login', 'login is required').notEmpty(),
    body('password', 'password is required').notEmpty()
];

exports.checkRules = (req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }
    next();
};
```

E aqui a declaração dos middlewares de validação na rota:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const loginService = require('../controllers/login.controller');
const loginValidator = require('../validators/login.validator');

router.post('/login', loginValidator.validationBodyRules, loginValidator.checkRules, loginService.logEmployee);

module.exports = router;
```

Aqui a estrutura de como está organizado a arquitetura do projeto:

```
.
├── _config.yml
├── _bin
│   └── www
├── _server
│   ├── controllers
|   |  └── login.controller.js
│   ├── routes
|   |  └── login.route.js
│   ├── validators
|   |  └── login.validator.js
│   └── index.js
├── package.json
└── app.js
```

Um exemplo completo pode ser visto no meu repositório pessoal no github (tokenauth)